# Convert Java map to json: Out of memory exception

Tags: java, json

I have a java Map that I would like to transform to json. A simplified version code is as follows:

```
Map<CallDetail, List<TaskDetail>> calls = callDetailService.getOutstandingPreRequisiteTasksForDependentCalls();
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer().transform(new MapTransformer(), Map.class);
String string = serializer.deepSerialize(calls);//this line throws an error when serializing
```

When the serialization happens, my server throws a **java.lang.outofmemoryerror** complaining that the java heap has run out of space.

Can anybody advise me on what is the best way to transform this map to json? I am currently using FlexJson.

Comment: Out of memory error is probably caused by a recursive call without a stopping condition.

Comment: With serialisation: still better have no cycles, a TaskDetail refering to a CallDetail; also use no embedded non-static classes which includes `new C() { ... }`. They have a `OuterClass.this` to the outer class.

Comment: This could happen if an element in the Map directly or indirectly points back at that Map.  The JSON serializer will "walk" the Map, and if it starts walking in circles you'd see this.

Comment: stupic question in stackoveflow.com: shouldn't recursion cause stack overflow error instead of heap problem?  how big is the object you are trying to serialize? btw: if you would post your whole exception including stacktrace we would see it more clearly if it is recursion problem or not.

Comment: @sodik - The serializer may or may not be implemented using recursion, and even with recursion, if a single "cycle" is creating a lot of serialized data you could run out of heap before you run out of stack.  (But it's a good point about posting the stack trace.)

Comment: @Sodik Thank you for your sarcastic answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The key of the map I was trying to serialize had references to other objects, which in turn had a reference back to the key itself. Hence the never-ending recursion and the heap running out of space